# LINQ - accessing an Int column on Child table and handle the situation when there are no child rows

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Here is a cut down version of my linq query;

```
 var list = from inv in db.Inventories
                       where inv.InventoryCode.StartsWith("005")
                       select
                       new
                       {
                           inv.InventoryCode,
                           inv.InventoryMedias.Where(im => im.MediaType == 0).FirstOrDefault().Synopsis,
                           inv.InventoryMedias.Where(im => im.MediaType == 0).FirstOrDefault().InventoryID
                       };
```

...because an inventory record does not have to have any rows in InventoryMedia, i have added the .FirstOrDefault(), which then returns a null and linq is smart enough not to throw an ONSTIOO error, but i do get this error.

> The cast to value type 'Int32' failed
>   because the materialized value is
>   null. Either the result type's generic
>   parameter or the query must use a
>   nullable type

Now i understand that i could just change the anonymous type to a class and define this integer as a nullable type, but i dont want to do that.  I have also tried using the if null command "?? 0", but that is not supported on reference types like int. I know i can use .DefaultIfEmpty() and set a default value for the anonymous type, but how can i set a default value for the integer or is there another alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try projecting to the desired properties first then use `FirstOrDefault()`.  That way you won't have to deal with the possibility of a null reference exception and the type will be whatever is appropriate for the property.  Cast to nullable if necessary.

```
var list = from inv in db.Inventories
           where inv.InventoryCode.StartsWith("005")
           select
           new
           {
               inv.InventoryCode,
               Synopsis = inv.InventoryMedias
                             .Where(im => im.MediaType == 0)
                             .Select(im => im.Synopsis)
                             .FirstOrDefault(),
               InventoryID = inv.InventoryMedias
                                .Where(im => im.MediaType == 0)
                                .Select(im => im.InventoryID)
                                .FirstOrDefault(),
           };
```

Comment: both answers acceptable, this one is a little neater. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

cast to an nullable int

```
int? value;
```

Comment: oh and then use the "?? 0".  if that works it will be too easy. thanks